# CSS three-column layout

Tags: css

I'm looking for the best way to accomplish the following layout. I need to accommodate a header and footer of varying size, of which I am not in control. In between those elements, I need to set up a fixed three column layout. The total layout needs to always print on one standard page in landscape mode. If I didn't have to allow for the header/footer, I know I could just use a fixed layout... but I can't. The layout needs to be:

variable height header
div with three fixed width columns
variable height footer

p.s. sorry, don't yet know the proper way to display this graphically here :(

Comment: Take a look at these 2 articles... - http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm - http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks The first article will describe how to set up the 3 columns and the second describes how to make them equal heights if you care about having unique background colors. I hope this helps. Hristo

Comment: something like what they do here? http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/        OR            http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to have text divided into three columns, for a treat, you could try CSS3's columns:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-multicol-20010118/
- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

This however, is not supported in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control how your page prints, use the @page rule, like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            @page
            {
                size:portrait;
                margin:1in;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>...</body>
</html>
```

More info on @page can be found on the W3C's [CSS 2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html).